# Addition with permutation and Combination of numbers

Tags: python-3.7

I have a requirement to dynamically get a set of numbers as inputs from users and perform sum of different combination of numbers to get a particular sum

In the below example I have got 6 numbers as input but it can vary from say 3 to 20
'''
Num_list = 6,5,4,3,2,1
Expected sum = 9

```
Following combinations give a sum of 9
```

- 6+3
  5+4
  6+2+1
  4+3+2

'''

Comment: Look at itertools https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 0):

As balderman noted, we can use functions from `itertools`, namely [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the subsequences, and [`filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) to drop the sequences where the sum isn't right:

```
Num_list = list(range(6, 0, -1))
Expected_sum = 9

import itertools

print("Num_list =", end=' ')
print(*Num_list, sep=',')
print("Expected sum =", Expected_sum)
print("Following combinations give a sum of", Expected_sum)
for e in itertools.filterfalse(lambda c: sum(c) != Expected_sum,
                               (c for r in range(1, 1+len(Num_list))
                                  for c in itertools.combinations(Num_list, r)
                              )):
    print(*e, sep='+')
```